# Oracle hierarchy query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, hierarchical-data

Scoured the interwebs for a few days looking for a solution to this hierarchy riddle but no luck.  All solutions I've found have either a row with parent ID null, have only one ultimate parent, or I'm just missing some piece of knowledge that's preventing me from adapting the solutions for the various needs out there to fit my need.

Data appears like so:

```
SELECT 3225 PARENT_ID,'TYPE2_A' PARENT,3227 CHILD_ID,'TYPE2_C' CHILD FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 148,'TYPE2_H',150,'TYPE2_G' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3225,'TYPE2_A',3226,'TYPE2_B' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3227,'TYPE2_C',3222,'TYPE3_E' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3220,'TYPE3_D',3221,'TYPE3_I' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3226,'TYPE2_B',3220,'TYPE3_D' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2379,'TYPE1_K',148,'TYPE2_H' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 113,'TYPE1_L',91,'TYPE3_F' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 148,'TYPE2_H',128,'TYPE3_N' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3223,'TYPE1_J',3226,'TYPE2_B' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2379,'TYPE1_K',150,'TYPE2_G' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 150,'TYPE2_G',91,'TYPE3_F' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2487,'TYPE1_A',3225,'TYPE2_A' FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98,'TYPE1_M',91,'TYPE3_F' FROM  DUAL;
```

- TYPE1 can never be a child, it's always a parent.
- TYPE1 can be a parent of either TYPE2 or TYPE3.
- TYPE2 can be a parent of either TYPE2 or TYPE3.
- TYPE2 can never be a child of TYPE3.
- TYPE3 can be a parent of TYPE3.
- TYPE2 and TYPE3 always have at least one TYPE1 ultimate parent but can have more than one TYPE1 parent.

**The goal of the query is to take a distinct list of all TYPE2 and TYPE3 children like so...**

```
SELECT PARENT FROM
(query from above)
WHERE PARENT LIKE 'TYPE2%' OR PARENT LIKE 'TYPE3%'
UNION
SELECT CHILD FROM
(query from above)
WHERE CHILD LIKE 'TYPE2%' OR CHILD LIKE 'TYPE3%';
```

**...and find who their ultimate TYPE1 parent(s) is.**

For example, based on the data set above...

- TYPE3_F has ultimate parents TYPE1_L and TYPE1_M
- TYPE3_E has ultimate parent TYPE1_A
- TYPE2_B has ultimate parents TYPE1_A and TYPE1_J

The result set for inputs TYPE3_F, TYPE3_E, and TYPE2_B would appear like...

```
Child     Ultimate_Parent
TYPE3_F   TYPE1_L
TYPE3_F   TYPE1_M
TYPE3_E   TYPE1_A
TYPE2_B   TYPE1_A
TYPE2_B   TYPE1_J
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the connect_by_root function to obtain the parent at the highest level, no matter where in the tree you started.

```
    with parent_child_data
    as
    (SELECT 2487    PARENT_ID,'TYPE1_A' PARENT, 3225 CHILD_ID,'TYPE2_A' CHILD FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3225 ,'TYPE2_A', 3226    ,'TYPE2_B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3225 ,'TYPE2_A', 3227    ,'TYPE2_C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3226 ,'TYPE2_B', 3220    ,'TYPE3_D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3227 ,'TYPE2_C', 3222    ,'TYPE3_E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 113  ,'TYPE1_L', 91  ,'TYPE3_F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 98   ,'TYPE1_M', 91  ,'TYPE3_F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2379 ,'TYPE1_K', 150 ,'TYPE2_G' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2379 ,'TYPE1_K', 148 ,'TYPE2_H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 150  ,'TYPE2_G', 1291    ,'TYPE3_F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 148  ,'TYPE2_H', 150 ,'TYPE2_G' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 148  ,'TYPE2_H', 128 ,'TYPE3_N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 150  ,'TYPE2_G', 1291    ,'TYPE3_F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3220 ,'TYPE3_D', 3221    ,'TYPE3_I' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3226 ,'TYPE2_B', 3220    ,'TYPE3_D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3223 ,'TYPE1_J', 3226    ,'TYPE2_B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3225 ,'TYPE2_A', 3226    ,'TYPE2_B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2487 ,'TYPE1_A', 3225    ,'TYPE2_A' FROM DUAL)
    select * from (
select d.child_id, d.child, d.parent_id, d.parent, connect_by_root d.parent ultimate_parent
from parent_child_data d
where child like 'TYPE3%' or child like 'TYPE2%'
connect by prior child_id = parent_id)
where ultimate_parent like 'TYPE1%' 
    ;
```

Comment: thanks Nick.  using this query and the de-duplicated, modified data sample I just edited in the post I'm seeing this result for Child =TYE2_B: `3226 TYPE2_B 3225 TYPE2_A TYPE1_A
3226 TYPE2_B 3223 TYPE1_J TYPE1_J
3226 TYPE2_B 3225 TYPE2_A TYPE2_A`

Comment: ***disregard the prior comment, I'm new to this thing***  thanks Nick.  using this query and the de-duplicated, modified data sample I just edited in the post I'm getting three parents for Child =TYE2_B: TYPE1_A, TYPE1_J, and TYPE2_A.  Child TYPE2_B should have only two ultimate parents: TYPE1_A and TYPE1_J.

Comment: Can you clarify your data further?  You have two Type1 records that are children records.  `SELECT 113,'TYPE1_L',91,'TYPE3_F' FROM  DUAL` .  This select implies record 113 which is a TYPE1 is a child of a TYPE3 record.

Comment: 113 is a PARENT_ID and TYPE1_L is a PARENT.  TYPE3_F is the child of parent TYPE1_L.  What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, in my mind I was reading child, then parent.  Regardless, solution adjusted to accommodate.

Comment: Thanks!  Although, your query is returning 6 rows for `CHILD` = `TYPE3_F`.  Four of the rows have duplicate `ULTIMATE_PARENT` = `TYPE1_K` and their `CHILD_ID` = `1291` instead of `91`. The remaining two rows look good.

Comment: Also, I updated the data set yesterday to remove several duplicate rows so use the one that's up there right now.  Using that data set with your solution gives a similar result but with only two duplicate rows instead of four.

Comment: Regarding the line in the query `where ultimate_parent like 'TYPE1%`, these values in reality will not be named in a similar manner in which a wildcard be used to filter.  The PARENT names will be totally dissimilar to one another.

Comment: Is changing the table structure an option?  In the typical hierarchical example of an employee database.  The table is structured as: